# "ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer" happens while tryng to log in vagrant box over ssh

Tags: ssh, vagrant

I was trying  to deploy 4 vagrant box of two different OS. two of them are Ubuntu and other two are Centos. My vagrant file configuration is below:-

```
config.vm.define "ubuntu" do |ubuntu|
    ubuntu.vm.hostname="ubuntu"
    ubuntu.vm.box="bento/ubuntu-17.10"
    ubuntu.vm.network "private_network", ip:"192.168.33.10"
  end
  config.vm.define "centos" do |centos|
    centos.vm.hostname="centos"
    centos.vm.box="bento/centos-7.4"
    centos.vm.network "private_network", ip:"192.168.33.20"
  end
  config.vm.define "server1" do |server1|
    server1.vm.hostname="server1"
    server1.vm.box="bento/ubuntu-17.10"
    server1.vm.network "private_network", ip:"192.168.33.30"
  end
  config.vm.define "server2" do |server2|
    server2.vm.hostname="server2"
    server2.vm.box="bento/centos-7.4"
    server2.vm.network "private_network", ip:"192.168.33.40"
  end
```

After successfully executing executing `vagrant up` I checked the `vagrant status` and found all box were running ok.

```
ubuntu                    running (virtualbox)
centos                    running (virtualbox)
server1                   running (virtualbox)
server2                   running (virtualbox)
```

however when I tried to login to each machine using `vagrant ssh ubuntu` , `vagrant ssh centos` , `vagrant ssh server1` ,`vagrant ssh server2` commands , every machine could be logged in except server1. While I tried to access server2 using `vagrant ssh server1` that error showed:-

```
"ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer"
```

I using vagrant 2.2.4 on my elementary OS Loki system. Seeking help from experienced.TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has solved. I dont no what was wrong actually! However, I tried following simple steps and fortunately it worked: 1. `vagrant destroy` 2. `vagrant up`